# Why are some transfers.ICUSTAY_ID null?

Tags: mimic-iii

Why is the `ICUSTAY_ID` null for some rows in the transfers table?

```
-- returns 174176 rows
SELECT * FROM mimiciii.transfers  
WHERE ICUSTAY_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY ICUSTAY_ID ASC ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfers table provides a record of the movements between wards made by patients during a hospital stay. Not all of the transfers listed in the table are made between intensive care units.

If the current care unit (`curr_careunit`) is an intensive care unit then we would expect the `icustay_id` to be populated. If the `curr_careunit` is not an intensive care unit, we would expect the `icustay_id` to be null.

An empty field in the `curr_careunit` or `prev_careunit` indicates that the care unit is not an intensive care unit. In addition, certain other entries may not be intensive care units (for example, 'NWARD' is a ward for newborns).

To summarise, all or almost all of the `icustay_id`s returned by your query are expected to be null because the `curr_careunit` is not an intensive care unit.